# Reg expression for certain letters in a email

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

In this expression below it checks for a valid email. My question is how can I check for ppl|pplweb is in the email address after the @ sign

```
!preg_match("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $email)
```

Thanks

Comment: Obviously, you don't much like `.info` domain holders. Not to mention `.museum`. Seriously, this is a bad regex to begin with. Don't try to validate an email address with regexen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can split your `$email` var in 2 components of the array separating it by the @ sign

```
$splitted_email = explode('@',$email);
```

and then search by the ppl/pp/web patterns in the first component of your array

```
preg_match('(/ppl|pplweb/i)',$splitted_email[1]);
```

this way, maybe the code is a bit longer but short regular expressions are better to mantain.

Comment: try `$splitted_email = explode('@',$email);` and match `$splitted_email[1]` instead of `$splitted_email[0]`. I submitted an edit to this answer that is waiting for peer review.

Comment: Also, the regular expression should be `'/ppl|pplweb/'`. Or if you  want a case-insensitive match: `'/ppl|pplweb/i'`.